# Powershell - How to use an 'enum' imported from a module as script parameter

Tags: powershell, module, enums, parameters

in a script I try to use an enum that is defined in a module.
Here's the script Sample.ps1:

```
 using module SampleModule
 param(
  [SampleEnum] $MyEnum
 )
 $MyEnum
```

and here's SampleModule.psm1:

```
  enum SampleEnum {
    A
    B
    C
  }
```

Starting Sample.ps1 from a fresh Powershell gives me the following error:

```
  PS C:\test> .\Sample.ps1
  Unable to find type [SampleEnum].
  At C:\test\Sample.ps1:3 char:2
  +  [SampleEnum] $MyEnum
  +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (SampleEnum:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

I can explicitly import the module from the shell like this:

```
  PS C:\test> using module SampleModule
  PS C:\test> .\Sample.ps1
  PS C:\test> .\Sample.ps1 A
  A
```

...but of course I want the script to be self-contained.
Why does the error occur and how to work-around it?

**Update to be more specific:**
Using the enum in the script body - not in the param declaration - *does* work, like here:

```
using module SampleModule
$MyEnum = [SampleEnum]::A
$MyEnum
```

Using `Import-Module` does not work in either scripts, it simply does not make the enum visible (see e.g. [enter link description here](https://stephanevg.github.io/powershell/class/module/DATA-How-To-Write-powershell-Modules-with-classes/)).

So my problem is to use the enum in the **param** of the script.

Comment: Is `SampleModuleSampleEnum` a typo, or is `[SampleModuleSampleEnum]` the actual type literal you use in the script?

Comment: Sorry, was a typo (see also the 'correct' enum in the error message), happened when copying/editing the question. Thanks for noting. Corrected now.

Comment: to be sure i have understood, you want to use a variable created and initialized in the module?could you show the complete code in your module ,how you initialize your variable in the module?

Comment: I want to use the enum type, which is defined in the module, as a type parameter in the param-list of the script. Above shows the full code of both, the script and the module (reduced to demonstrate the problem of course).

Comment: ok i understant better your problem..

Comment: i dont see the path neither extension of your module in the using expression, its just a typo? that is not functional by me without that

Comment: so i havent problem..maybe have you an old version of PS

Comment: PS-version is 5.1.19041.906. With extension it does not work for me (`using module SampleModule.psm1` gives an error that the module cannot be found)

Comment: Seems to me that the enum defined in the module is simply not yet available at the time you're calling on the script, so then inside the `param()` block it has no knowledge yet that type `[SampleEnum]` exists. Your latest edit shows that by defining it beforehand, it does exist and works.

Comment: Yes, seems to me as well. Just I find it strange and not consequent: you *must* put the `using module` first before any other statement - also before the `param` - else you get a respective error; but it does not have an effect on the `param`. I was looking for a "formal" definition/specification how exactly that "using module" works, but did not find it yet. Any pointer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this, too (with PS v5.1.17763.2090).

As far as I can tell (I haven't disassembled to verify, but this is what it looks like based on a simple script's behavior), a PSM's param() clause is evaluated first, therefore any types that should be imported by the `using` statement are unknown at that point.

Best workaround I could find would be to use basic types, then convert them, as follows:

```
 using module SampleModule
 param(
  [UInt64] $MyEnum
 )
 $MyEnum = [Enum]::ToObject([SampleEnum],$MyEnum)
```